# How do I set up a unidirectional one-to-one association in Sequel?

Tags: ruby, orm, sequel

For the tables in the following mock schema:

```
Owner:
 id
 name
 business_id

Business:
 id
 name
```

I would like to have a **unidirectional** association from the owner to the business. I can't modify the schema to add a owner_id to the business table. How do I do this?

This is what I would expect to make it work:

```
class Business < Sequel::Model
  set_allowed_columns :name, 
end

class Owner < Sequel::Model
  set_allowed_columns :name, 
  one_to_one :business, reciprocal: nil
end
```

Comment: `one_to_one :business` should work and try `one_to_one :owner, key: :business_id`

Comment: can't edit my comment but try `one_to_one :owner, key: :business_id` in your `Business` model and `one_to_one :business, key: :business_id` in your `Owner` model. I am not very familiar with Sequel but reading the [docs](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/association_basics_rdoc.html) this seems feasible. Or look at the `:left_key` and `:right_key` options.